# "abort: no suitable response from remote hg!"

Tags: mercurial

I've just created a new Mercurial repo on my private server, but I can't push to it, and I can't figure out why.

Here's what I see:

```
 % hg push
pushing to ssh://hg@mydomain.com//var/repos/myrepo
abort: no suitable response from remote hg!
```

On the server, the repo exists, and I can clone it locally:

```
root@mydomain:/tmp# hg clone /var/repos/myrepo repoclone
updating to branch default
0 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
```

I created the repo with `hg init myrepo`. It's owned by `hg:hg`, mod 755.

My workstation and server are both running

```
Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 4.4.1)
```

What else might be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Discovered you can add `--debug` to `hg push`.

```
 % hg --debug push
pushing to ssh://hg@mydomain.com//var/repos/myrepo
running ssh 'hg@mydomain.com' 'hg -R /var/repos/myrepo serve --stdio'
sending hello command
sending between command
remote: This account is currently not available.
abort: no suitable response from remote hg!
```

I guess the server user must have a shell.

```
nano /etc/passwd
```

Changed

```
hg:x:999:1002:Mercurial repo owner:/home/hg:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

to

```
hg:x:999:1002:Mercurial repo owner:/home/hg:/bin/bash
```

And now it pushes!